# Installing Anaconda or Python on Sun Solaris 11.4 with Sparc architecture

Tags: python, anaconda, solaris, sparc, sun

I am trying to install Python or anaconda on Sun solaris 11.4 system with Sparc architecture. Somebody has idea on the python or anaconda installer compatible to same

Comment: Solaris 11.4 includes several versions of Python already - including 2.7, 3.5, & 3.7 - you should be able to just `pkg install python-27 python-35 python-37` to get them all installed under `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

The following info is from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/download/other/)

> #### Python for Solaris
>
> You can purchase [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/) (commercial and community versions, including scientific computing modules, not open source), or build from [source](https://www.python.org/download/source) if you have a C compiler.
>
> [UNIX Packages](http://www.unixpackages.com/) has a variety of Python versions for a variety of Solaris versions. These use the standard Sun pkgadd.

As far as I know, Anaconda supports ONLY Windows, MacOs and Linux.

---

Above the facts, now the opinions...

1. In my experience building Python from source is easy, but when you want to pull in the scientific stack (Numpy, Matplotlib, Scipy, Cartopy etc) building from source becomes more complicated (I don't know if you can `pip` these libraries pre-built for Solaris).
2. I've learnt, reading [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/python-on-solaris) and [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/future-of-python-on-solaris) that Solaris indeed comes with Python, but this pre-installed Python issue is meant, essentially, for use by a large number of important OS components and you'd better leave it alone.

   If, for your development, you can use the system's Python as is, no other modules installed, no newer versions etc, then you're OK

   On the other hand, the documents linked above details the practices Oracle
   suggests to install additional packages w/o disrupting the system's Python.

Be careful...

Comment: I have Solaris 11.4/SPARC, which is used for Oracle database & RAC.  These have their own set of packages that must be installed.  Python 3.7 cannot be installed on top of this with 'pkgadd', as it has pre-requisites that conflict with already installed software.